# Using Excel columns in Python and defining which is x and y

Tags: python, excel, histogram

I have imported a file from Excel into Python. I am using pandas and matplotlib. The Excel spreadsheet contains two columns, one for discharge and one for frequency. I would like to make a histogram of the data and put the discharge on the x-axis and frequency on the y-axis.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have the frequency for each discharge, i.e. all the histogram bins are present, you can just create a barchart with your data.

```
df.plot.bar(x='discharge', y='frequency', rot=0)
```